# How to set up a bootable Truecrypt USB with Ubuntu on it?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, encryption, truecrypt

Oddly enough, I haven't found the solution to this yet, unless I've misinterpreted the search results I've been seeing.

I want to encrypt a USB flash drive so that I can select "Boot from USB" on any machine, and Truecrypt will load from the drive itself and then Ubuntu will boot from the decrypted drive.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu on the flash drive and then use Truecrypt inside Ubuntu to encrypt it.

Truecrypt can encrypt the OS partition while the OS is running, then all you have to do is reboot and you'll be prompted to provide your password.